# "apart from" vs "other than" vs "aside from" vs "except for" vs "besides"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-difference

I have a question regarding the usage of "apart from", "other than", "aside from", "except for" and "besides"?

Suppose I have three books X, Y and Z. My friend knows I have Book X. So if he wants to know how many books I have along with X, Which of the above phrases are correct?

> - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **besides** X?
> - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **other than** X?
> - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **apart from** X?
> - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **aside from** X?
> - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **except for** X?

I think all of the above are correct but **except for**. I am not sure. Am I right?

And one more question: Suppose a contractor who paints houses asks me "Hi, sir, do you want to paint your kitchen?" I answer, "No, at the moment; I don't think it needs to be painted." Now in these circumstances, which of the following phrases should the contractor use when asks the next question?

> **Contractor**: Hi, sir, do you want to paint your kitchen?
>   **Me**: No, at the moment; I don't think it needs to be painted.
>   **Contractor**: Do you want to paint anything in your house **other than/except for/apart from/besides** your kitchen?

I think *besides* is not correct here. The rest of all the phrases are correct. I am not sure. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas *besides* denotes inclusion/adding to, *except/except for* has the meaning of exclusion and so does *other than* which means [with the exception of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20than).

As for *apart from* and   [*aside from*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside%20from), they may mean both inclusion and exclusion.

So all your sentences are valid, in my opinion.

[(Also, see this video lesson)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjMReSqdZVw)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment Victor B.'s great answer but I don't have enough reputation, so I will leave an answer here.

Victor concludes that OP's sentences are all valid, and I agree. However, I feel like OP also wants to ask that if the sentences are (or are not) reasonable, given the scenario he described.

Based on knowledge from Victor's answer, I think OP's right with the painter-kitchen question.
As for the book question, I think not only *except for*, but also *other than* should be excluded from the correct answers, since they both have the meaning of exclusion, which is inappropriate in the book scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question as all of these connectives involve separating out a certain element of a set.

> > - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **besides** X?
> > - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **other than** X?
> > - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **apart from** X?
> > - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **aside from** X?
> > - Hey Subha, how many books do you have **except for** X?
>
> I think all of the above are correct but **except for**. I am not sure. Am I right?

I agree. I think **except for** can only be used when describing a property that applies to some elements of a set but not others. The [Collins COBUILD definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/except-for) is:

> You use **except for** to introduce the only thing or person that prevents a statement from being completely true.

It implies a negation:

- I like all snacks **except (for)** pretzels. => I do not like pretzels.
- Everyone **except (for)** Sam attended. => Sam did not attend.

Whereas **besides**, **other than**, etc. are about limiting the set under discussion for purposes of the "how many?" question. **Excluding** would also work here.

---

> **Contractor:** Hi, sir, do you want to paint your kitchen?
> **Me:** No, at the moment; I don't think it needs to be painted.
> **Contractor:** Do you want to paint anything in your house **other than/except for/apart from/besides** your kitchen?

In this scenario it would be more natural to say something like: "Are there any other rooms that need painting?" Or, if mentioning the kitchen: "If not the kitchen, do you want me to paint any of the other rooms?" (The kitchen is topical—it was just discussed—so it would be typical to re-mention it at the beginning of the sentence, before the new information asking about other rooms.)

"Is there anything...**except for**" sounds odd because **except for** usually accompanies an expression referring to a complete set of items; it would be appropriate if the discussion was about painting *all* the other rooms:

- Would you like me to paint all the rooms **except for** the kitchen?

"**Besides** your kitchen" could be interpreted as "in addition to your kitchen", which is not the intended meaning. But I could imagine somebody saying it in this scenario. **Other than, apart from, aside from** also sound OK.